# How to make nginx include any of the index files that are hidden in the URL?

Tags: nginx, indexing, url-rewriting

So when I browse to my website https://www.example.com/somefolder, there is an index file (ex.: index.php) and the page loads fine.  However, in the browser URL bar, it only shows "https://www.example.com/somefolder".  I know nginx served the ***index.php*** file since it is listed in the index section.  How do we make sure any of the index files always show up without making the remote client explicitly manually type the index file on their side?

Comment: See [the `index` directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

Comment: May I ask you what is the purpose of such a strange requirements? This can be achieved either with a complex redirection rules within nginx config or (and this would be much better since it would not require additional redirection) with a few javascript lines attached to your generated content.

Comment: yeah, I don't want to manipulate the URL bar using JavaScript param object.  I will go with the nginx config rewrite tweak

Comment: This would be incompatible with the solution I gave you on your previous question since you'll need to override default nginx `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` behavior.

Comment: ahhh...I see.  hmmm.. I wonder in order for all requirements to remain if we should remove the index.php from the index and use the other 403 redirection to try index.php first before redirecting to the root....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to preserve as much original behavior as I could, try this:

```
map $uri $maybe_slash {
    ~/$      '';
    default  '/';
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri @check_index;
    }
    location @check_index {
        if ( -f $document_root$uri${maybe_slash}index.php ) { return 301 $uri${maybe_slash}index.php; }
        # if we also need to check for "index.html", uncomment next line
        # if ( -f $document_root$uri${maybe_slash}index.html ) { return 301 $uri${maybe_slash}index.html; }
        return 301 /index.php;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very impressive.  It resolve the question.  I'll go away before I add to these requirements further.. ;D this further.  Thank you.